# Is there an celestial equivalent to an imp/quasit?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, familiars

Introduced in the early editions of D&D, imps and quasits were presented as devil/demon familiar options for evil spellcasters, and as of fifth edition, this aspect of them hasn't changed.

However, I could never find a similar creature that was good aligned, or more appropriately, tied to celestial creatures/plane that can act as a familiar. Is there one?

If one such creature doesn't exist, it is good enough to present good-aligned extraplanar creatures that share similar traits to imps/quasits such as:

- Is Tiny
- Low level/CR

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question before, but I can't find it... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kuerten Are you looking for the creatures to also be familiars?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons*, a magic-user that casts the spell *find familiar* could gain a special familiar according to the caster's alignment if the DM rolls (in secret, naturally) exactly 15 on 1d20. (To be clear, a result of 1–14 yields a more pedestrian black cat, crow, hawk, screech owl, toad, or weasel, and a result of 16–20 yields no familiar—better luck next year!) Special familiars include a quasit for a CN or CE caster, an imp for a LE or NE caster, a **brownie** for a LN or LG caster, and a **pseudo-dragon** for CG, NG, and N casters. In other words, the early game didn't seem to think it necessary to extend special familiar parity all the way to making *all* special familiars extraplanar.

(The *Player's Handbook* for *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons, 2nd Edition* (and, by extension, the *Wizard's Spell Compendium*) eliminates the possibility of special familiars from the *find familiar* spell. A result of 15—20 meant trying again later.)

### *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* allows a caster of good alignment to gain as a familiar either a coure, a lantern archon, or a musteval

In *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5*, the **imp** (*Monster Manual* 56), a [devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)), and the **quasit** (46), a [demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)), are available to lawful and chaotic evil arcane casters, respectively, that take the feat **Improved Familiar** (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 200) and that possess an arcane caster level of at least 7. Further, the **formian worker** (108–9), a formian (obviously), or any **mephit** (*MM* 180–5 *et al.*) is available to a similar caster that possesses an alignment of LN or N, respectively. (Mephits in general are made available by page 78 of *Complete Scoundrel*.) Both the formian worker and mephits, however, possess size categories of Small rather than Tiny.

By comparison, an appropriate creature that possesses an arcane caster level of at least 7 can take the feat **Celestial Familiar** (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 41), dismiss her current familiar if any, and perform the 100-gp familiar-summoning ritual to gain either a **coure** (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 168–9), an eladrin; a [**lantern archon**](http://dndsrd.net/monstersA.html#lantern-archon) (*MM* 16), an archon; or a **musteval** (*BE* 174), a guardinal depending on if her alignment is CG, LG, or NG, respectively. (It's a mystery to this *3.5* fan why the feat Celestial Familiar even exists when other texts just expand the options of the feat Improved Familiar, but that's *3.5* for you.) The lantern archon's size category is Small, but the other two are Tiny.

A lantern archon is pretty much just a ball of light, but the *Book of Exalted Deeds* has evocative illustrations of the **coure** and of the **musteval**.

[image]<sup>**A coure eladrin**</sup>

[image]<sup>**A musteval guardinal**</sup>

(Both creatures are about the size of a typical real-world house cat.) All of these *3.5* creatures are extraplanar in origin. To my knowledge the CN alignment is unrepresented. There's no option for a kooky CN magician to have as a familiar, for instance, a Tiny extraplanar slaad-like creature. (A side slaad?)

Comment: Good argument for ADD.

Comment: Your side slaad comes with a bleu cheese dressing, I gather. ;-)

Answer (score 14):

## [Mustevals](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Musteval)

Mustevals are neutral good celestials, who are tiny humanoid-mouse like celestials who can disguise themselves using change self. They are spies and messengers of more powerful celestials, and the Harpers know of rituals to summon them for aid, for up to a year.

That, to me at least, sounds a lot like getting a tiny familiar for a year, and it could even perform much of the same role as an Imp could. It lacks any stats outside of D&D 3e, but that is something that can easily be houseruled.

Answer (score 5):

Closest in 3.5 is probably a Lantern Archon. They're CR2, small rather than tiny though. Avalable via the Planar Familiar feat in the Planar Handbook.

Comment: I was going to say hollyphants, but they have the same problem (size).

Answer (score 3):

### [Psuedodragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pseudodragon)

> **Draconic Familiars.** Mages often seek out
>   pseudodragons, whose agreeable disposition, telepathic
>   ability, and resistance to magic make them superior
>   familiars. Pseudodragons are selective when it comes
>   to choosing companions, but they can sometimes
>   be won o~er with gifts of food or treasure. When
>   a pseudodragon finds an agreeable companion, it
>   bonds with that person as long as it is treated fairly.
>   A pseudodr.agon puts up with no ill treatment, and
>   it abandons a manipulative or abusive companion
>   without warning.

Comment: A pseudodragon is not a celestial, right?

Comment: @Medix2 the OP asks about “good aligned” with celestial as a qualifier

Comment: @Medix2 Pseudodragon summoned with *Find Familiar* Pact of the Chain variant can be a celestial.

Comment: @AntiDrondert So can quasits and imps, and that's a game mechanics and not a lore answer. OP is looking for creatures that fit that type, not spells that creature a creature posing as another type.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question because pseudodragons aren't extraplanar creatures.

Comment: @anti this Q asks for fluff, not crunch.